How to create a custom color map
I need to create a custom cmap. I have made a dictionary of color and associated value from image:
{
    100: "RGB(170, 170, 170)",
    75: "RGB(90, 0, 0)",
    50: "RGB(180, 0, 0)", 
    30: "RGB(255, 150, 0)",
    20: "RGB(255, 250, 0)",
    10:"RGB(0, 210, 0)",
    5: "RGB(0, 120, 0)",
    2.5: "RGB(70, 70, 200)",
    1: "RGB(150, 150, 255)",
    0.5: "RGB(220, 220, 255)",
    0.1: "RGB(230, 230, 230)",
    0:'RGB(255,255,255)'
}

I have extracted the colors from this image, I'd like to cmap exactly like this.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

# Generate random data
np.random.seed(42)  # for reproducibility
x, y, c = zip(*np.random.rand(30, 3) * 105 - 2)
# Define the color dictionary
color_dict = {
    0: 'white', 
    0.1: "blue",
    0.5: "pink",
    1: "lightblue",
    2.5: "blue",
    5: "darkgreen",
    10: "green",
    20: "yellow",
    30: "orange",
    50: "red",
    75: "brown",
    100: "grey",
    105: "grey"  
}
cvals = list(color_dict.keys())
colors = list(color_dict.values())

cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(colors)
norm = mcolors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries=cvals, ncolors=len(colors))
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
scatter = plt.scatter(x, y, c=c, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
cbar = plt.colorbar(scatter, extend='both')
cbar.set_ticks(cvals[1:-1]) 
cbar.set_ticklabels([str(val) for val in cvals[1:-1]])  

plt.title("Custom ListedColormap with Pointy Ends")
plt.show()


currently , i have output like this ,i am facing issue due to extends='both' property , and i need to do this compulsory, currently i am trimming the value cvals ,100 should be at top of colorbar ,from then grey color should appear in arrow region, same for lower section,you can compare images (arrow portion) to find difference


actually i tried to follow some previous solution posted on stackoverflow,but that didnot seem to help me properly
i found one solution close to me
but i got issue on normalization, as norm expects normalized data, from 0 to 1, but when i normalized, colorbar won't show range from 0.1 to 100 with same gap,
i wish i can attach code sample here

You can include code in the same way that you included your color dictionary above.  In fact it is highly recommended to include a minimal reproducible example.

please go through post again, i have edited the post, but i cannot add my output picture,   btw  my old issue is fixed, but new one appears

The color for the top triangle can be set via cmap.set_over(...). Similar for cmap.set_under('white'). Note that the number of bounds needs to be one more than the number of colors.
